# How to calculate maximum induced voltage

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields

My prof gave our class a challenge problem and I'm having some problem solving it.

At t=0, the position is given by the diagram. Which direction should I move the loop so that I get a max $V_{in}$ (maximum induced voltage)?
[image: Diagram]

**Attempt**

Because current is going in 2 directions, I'm guessing superposition would be necessary to find $\phi_m$

$\phi_{m1} = $ flux due to the current going up
$\phi_{m2} = $ flux due to the current going right

Because the loop is moving, the magnetic field will change over time so these formulas will represent changes in position over time in both $x$ and $y$:
$z(t) = d + v_xt$
$p(t) = d + v_yt$

$x$ will represent the distance from the $y$-axis
$y$ will represent the distance from the $x$-axis but going down is positive

$\phi_{m1} = \int_{z(t)}^{z(t)+d} B \cdot ds = \int_{z(t)}^{z(t)+d} (\frac{u_oI}{2\pi x})\cdot adx = \frac{u_oIa}{2\pi}\int_{z(t)}^{z(t)+d}\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{u_oIa}{2\pi}ln(\frac{z(t)+d}{z(t)}) $

$\phi_{m2} = \int_{p(t)}^{p(t)+d} B \cdot ds = \frac{u_oIb}{2\pi} \int_{p(t)}^{p(t)+d} \frac{dy}{y} = \frac{u_oIb}{2\pi}ln(\frac{p(t)+d}{p(t)})$

$\phi = \phi_{m1} + \phi_{m2} =\frac{u_oIa}{2\pi}ln(\frac{z(t)+d}{z(t)}) + \frac{u_oIb}{2\pi}ln(\frac{p(t)+d}{p(t)}) $

$V_{in} = -\frac{d\phi_m}{dt}$

After substituting the equation for $v(t)$ and $p(t)$ and solving the derivative I would take the derivative again and set it to $0$. I then thought about solving for $v_x$ and $v_y$ and then by using superposition I would be able to find the direction to move this object but I end up with $2$ unknown variables ($v_x$ and $v_y$) but only 1 equation (the derivative of $V_{in}$). Am I missing something with my calculation?

Comment: Hi Spencer and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: @JohnRennie thank you for letting me know! I'll keep that in mind for the future

Comment: $v_x^2+v_y^2=v^2$, a constant.